# PHP - GET parameter

Tags: php, post, parameters, get

i need help with my code:

Im including pages in index.php like:

```
if(isset($_GET['xx'])
{   
   // include('yy/'.$_GET['xx'].'.php');
}
```

and now in the file page.php i wanna use get parameters like from and to.
i use htaccess for short url

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)$ ./main.php?xx=$1
```

So i get this url in final:

```
index.php?xx=page?from=a&to=b
```

**When i print_r($_GET) i got only first parameter xx**

$_POST parameter works fine, but i need it with $_GET.

Comment: index.php?xx=page&from=a&to=b

Comment: ^ that is correct and the question is a typo.

Comment: Vote to close as typo

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. I know this is a right way how to get them all. But im including with get parameter page and on this page i wanna get other parameters.

Comment: access each via the key in `$_GET`. `$_GET['from'];` `$_GET['to'];`

Comment: also as a security check, be careful about what is being sent via `$_GET` before you call `include()`.

Comment: This is cutted version, i know thanks :)

Comment: By specifying your own query string in the replacement, you are discarding the original one - this is default behavior with mod_rewrite. You need to specify the QSA flag to keep it. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: @misorude this is what im finding. Thanks! God bless you!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
by **misorude**

> By specifying your own query string in the replacement, you are
>   discarding the original one - this is default behavior with
>   mod_rewrite. You need to specify the QSA flag to keep it.
>   httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Thanks for fast responds without reading. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the URL:

```
index.php?xx=page?from=a&to=b
```

It should be

```
index.php?xx=page&from=a&to=b
```

You put `?` in there twice instead of a `&`

Comment: I know this is a right way how to get them all. But im including with get parameter page and on this page i wanna get other parameters.